# How to ignore text/strings in google sheet Sum calculation?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

If I have a Text in a sum calculation which I would like to ignore. On the picture below you can see my formula. The text OFF is throwing an error on total hours for me. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You could try: `=FILTER(B4:O4,B3:O3="Start")-FILTER(B4:O4,B3:O3="End")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SUM function is pointless the way you have written it as you're already calculating the result with `+` and `-` operators (which is why you get the error). Try:

```
=SUM(C4,E4,G4,I4,K4,M4,O4)-SUM(B4,D4,F4,H4,J4,L4,N4)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. It worked for me. I am quite a beginner at excel and would like to learn the basics. please let me know if you can direct me to any good resources.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
=SUMIF(B3:O3,"End",B4:O4)-SUMIF(B3:O3,"Start",B4:O4)
```